# Unable to reject edits in documentation reviews queue

Tags: bug, documentation, review-queues

As the title suggests, I am unable to reject edits in documentation review queues. When I click on reject button it shows an error message stating:

> An error occurred. Please try after sometime.

I tried multiple times but I am still not able to do so.

**EDIT:**

Now I can't even Approve Changes in review queues

Here is the screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Happened to me yesterday as well. I tried to reject as plagiarism, but couldn't. After setting up a filter (e.g. [c]) things got worse. Then even _Skip_ failed with that error.

Comment: @honk even markdown is not showing changes properly

Comment: This is another [review](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/94102) that failed for me. I get a 500 when posting.

Comment: This just happened to me too with [this review](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/89011).

Comment: @PetrR.: Same for me in the same review. Status-completed? No way!

Comment: There's more than one bug affecting certain reviews - looking :(

Comment: Just tried to reject a blatant copy-paste. First I got this bug (again), then when I tried to reject it again, three robo-reviewers had approved it. Can we please destroy this particular review queue? It's doing more harm than good.

Comment: I had a short discussion about this in the [comments section on this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334638/812149). Apparently this bug only affects some users; maybe a privilege issue - e.g. only users below 10K are affected?

Comment: Those still occurs. Can't reject any change due to any reason. Approving is working.

Comment: Happened again. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/108579) is obviously a review audit. When I try to Reject it as Vandalism, I get the "An error has occurred" popup. I've tried it 3 times with the same result.

Answer (score -12):

This has been fixed in the latest deploy.  What was going on was pretty subtle.

Basically:

- Before applying a change we always re-validate it
- When a change is applied, all other outstanding changes that affect the same documents are merged with the now-applied change
- If an attempt to merge a change fails, the outstanding change is rejected as conflicting* with an approved change

The bug was it was possible for a merge to succeed, but result in a "change" that didn't actually modify anything.  When the change was then reviewed, validation would be run and it would fail.

We now correctly detect this case, and reject changes as conflicting appropriately.  Old proposed changes that got into this state have been cleaned up as well.

<sub>*Rejected as conflicting is different from normal rejection, as it doesn't indicate that there was anything wrong with the change - it just cannot be applied.  The Proposed Change Review Queue does not yet display this state as distinct from normal rejection, but will soon.</sub>

Comment: This is still occuring.

Comment: Some succeed, some fail, some ""This draft cannot be approved as it is in an invalid state."

Comment: <s>One time</s> Several times skipping even errored on me.

Comment: We'd also like "Approve and edit" and "Reject and edit" buttons too.

Comment: Now all three buttons are broken.

Comment: This still doesn't work. Specifically rejecting — approval is fine.