# Skip button bug while reviewing documentation

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, review-queues

I came across a review and I tried to skip it but it didn't work for first time though worked on second time but the major problem is, I again got the same review but this time, the skip button is not working no matter how many times I press it, as shown in the `gif` below:

[image]

Comment: there is a bug in every button in documentation right now

Comment: i looked for the answer but couldn't find any question or answer, so that's why raised the concern here .

Comment: I have added a question yesterday and there were few others also

Comment: i went through the question queue with these kind of bugs search tag,couldn't found any, anyway i hope this should be solved quickly

Comment: Here is the link for one I asked http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334349/unable-to-reject-edits-in-documentation-reviews-queue. Anyway this should be resolved asap

Comment: Seems like we got almost same bug for different buttons :p plus i learned something new to create a gif of screen :P:P

Comment: Looking at the [revisions for this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/334415/revisions) is strangely compelling...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be fixed now (i.e. there are no reviews that blow up!).

Ping me if you start seeing this again, please.

Comment: yeah , i believe in you :D