# Cannot reject Documentation Change

Tags: bug, documentation, review-queues

I'm working through the review queue for *Documentation: Proposed Changes*.

I wanted to reject [this change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/108984) with a custom message:

> This change advertises, but does not add relevant information. Please
>   be more specific.

However Stackoverflow rejects my review and shows a red box, saying:

> An error has occurred - please try your action again.

I tryed again and again, but the behaviour stays the same.

Comment: See also [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334349/unable-to-reject-edits-in-documentation-reviews-queue). I am NOT voting to close as duplicate, because it may have different causes. I discussed this with Jon Ericsson in the Tavern on the Meta last weekend. SO should be looking into it now.

Comment: We are looking at these reports. The more information we can gather the better. As you might know, intermittent, seemingly non-determinate bugs are difficult to solve. So hang in there and continue to report the details of any new instances you run across.

Comment: @JonEricson I just tried to reject [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/109350). Four times, same result. (Also please suspend anyone from review who Approves it - it's a question, not Documentation).

Comment: I can add that although the behavior may be non-determinate over users, it is determinate for me. I have never been able to reject documentation changes (windows, firefox 50). I can skip however.

Comment: I have the same issue. I can approve and skip, but every time I try to reject, I get the same error. (openSUSE 13.1, Firefox 49.0.2, even with all addons disabled)

Comment: Same here - always returns "an error occurred" - not the most informative error-message. Win 10, Firefox 50 (but the problem was there before I updated to ver. 50) - Also present in OSX El Capitan with Firefox 50.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/113755) and many others have given me the same error.

Answer (score 2):

The edit has been [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/108984) as spam:

> Contains spam, defaces the page, or is otherwise inappropriate.

This rejection *did* take me to the next review. I can't talk for custom rejection reasons, but the standard ones work as intended.

However, I did just experience that error trying to approve [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/108921).

Comment: When I wanted to reject it, it had not yet been rejected by anyone else. Now it (of course) has been rejected by others.

Comment: While that is good to know, it doesn't answer the deeper question - the bug with the Reject button. I had trouble Rejecting that thing myself.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: In other words, you were capable of reproducing the bug?

Comment: @Cerbrus Off the top of my head, I didn't reproduce it on this one, but it didn't take me to the next review item either. I did reproduce it on a few other items.

Comment: Regarding your edit: these bugs affect only some users. From what I've seen it only affects users below 10K, but there is not yet sufficient data to say for sure.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: I managed to reproduce the issue on a different review. Rep doesn't seem to matter.