# Can't review documentation change

Tags: bug, documentation, review-queues

This is something similar with this: [Cannot reject Documentation Change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337610/cannot-reject-documentation-change).

I try to reject the following change https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/110363 with a custom message (check below).

[image]

But I get an error saying to try again later. Apparently the reject results in an ajax request that is immediatly ovewritten by a get request (and page is refreshed). I also added a console print (for the canceled ajax).

[image]

Educated guess: My guess is that there should be a callback for that ajax calling the redirect on success (or there should be no ajax call).